# Mostrar valores de tabla en formulario PHP modelo POO

Tags: php

Debo cargar los valores de una tabla en un formulario *Modal*, pude hacer que muestre la lista de mis usuarios, pero cuando selecciono uno para editar su información en un modal, capturo el ID y hago la consulta, me trae la información, pero da error al asignarle al *value* de un text input:

Esta es mi Función:

```
public function get_busca_usuario($idusuario){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = '$idusuario'";
        $resultado = $this->conectar()->query($sql);
        $usuarios = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $usuarios;
      }


<form method="POST" id="editarUsuarios" action ="">
                            <?php
                            include("usuariosmod.php");                         
                            $usuarios = new usuarios();
                            $filas=$usuarios->get_busca_usuario($codigousuario);
                            print_r("<pre>");
                            print_r($filas);
                            print_r("<pre>");
                            
                            ?>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <label>Codigo</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $codigousuario?>" tabindex ="1"readonly>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                                    <label>Nombre Completo</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombrec" name="nombrec"  value="<?php echo $fila['name'] ?>" tabindex ="2" onkeypress="nextFocus('nombrec', 'username')">
                                </div>
```

Exactamente al mostrar *value* del input text `nombrec` es donde me genera error, y no entiendo que hago mal.
El error que genera es :
Undefined variable: nombrec in :

como si no existiera.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? Pulsa en [edit] para agregarlo.

Comment: Tienes un error tipográfico. Cambia `echo $fila['name']` por `echo $filas['name']` (con **s**) pues tu variable se llama **$filas** y no **$fila**.